# Ruby-on-rails deactivate change in time because of daylight saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone, save, dst

I have set my rails application to use the Chilean time zone. This year the government decided not to change the time for winter (as mentioned e.g. in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Chile)). Despite this, my application changed the time. So my question is:

How do I setup rails so it won't change the time automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I believe you'll struggle a lot with this. I'm not even sure if it's possible.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL - Why would you say such a thing?  If you *know* something is not possible, then you could answer explaining why it is the case.  But if you're just not sure if it is or isn't, then either do the research to find out, or let someone else answer.

Comment: So, I'm not a rails user, but in general, I would expect the OS to handle this.  What OS/version are you running, and did the underlying system time change or is your system clock set to GMT and rails is only adjusting the time displayed?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html):

> The `TimeZone class` serves as a wrapper around `TZInfo::Timezone` instances.
>
> ...
>
> If a recent version of the gem is installed locally, this will be used instead of the bundled version.

So, simply update to a current release of [the tzinfo gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/).

The specific change you are talking about for Chile was made in version 2015a of the underlying tz database. [Announcement here](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2015-January/000028.html).

This corresponds to version 1.2015.1 of the tzinfo-data gem, which supplies data to the tzinfo gem.  Install at least this version or higher, and you will have the Chilean DST change.

Comment: Also note that it's possible that you might not have to do anything more than just update Rails itself, or update your underlying OS data (if running on Linux).  I don't work with Rails much, so I have no idea how to check which version of TZInfo is bundled with which version of Rails.  Perhaps someone else can answer to that part of it.